# ClickOnce did not produce setup.exe file

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, clickonce, manifest

I'v been playing around with clickonce all day and it's really a head ache. After after tired of receiving several failed downloads from the app i decided to turn the last digit of the version to 0 so it's 1.0.0.0, delete all the contents of the publish folder and run the publish wizard again, only this time i noticed a .exe file was not published... I only saw the "Application files" folder and "myappname.application"... is this normal?

Why didn't it create a setup.exe file again like originally?

Comment: Inside of Application Files, you'll have a folder for each version. And the exe should be there called app.exe.deploy

Comment: @Engerlost it's there yes..but the first ever publish i did created a setup.exe file which was like 417kb big...i used it to install the application...now when i did the new publish it didn't create another

Answer (score 0):

Cleaned solution Within VS then deleted everything from old publish and published again